# symfony - nestedSet and rendering of parent/child nodes

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have created a model using the doctrine nestedSet behaviour in Symfony1.4, as I'm trying to create a basic cms, with heiracrchial pages.

I have a couple of pages, with parent and child nodes

```
Parent_1
   Child_1
   Child_2
Parent_2
   Child_3
```

My problem comes with rendering these items in terms of a navigation header. (`<ul><li>` etc)

What would be the easiest/best way to do this?

I'd like the `root` nodes to have URLs such as `/parent_1` and subsequent child nodes, be `parent_1/child_1`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a recursive function that will draw the tree starting from any node.  Specifying the root node will draw the entire tree.  It is used in my cart plug-in, and you can view a demo of the completed UI [here](http://cart.samedraw.com/cartadmin/categoryIndex).

I have pasted the function below, but modified it from my implementation to make it more clear.

```
<?php
//Render a nested set.  Recurses for all descendants of that node. Can be used to draw entire tree, when specifying root id.
//Secondary parameter ($node) is used for performance boost, internally in function.
public static function display_node($id, $node = null) {

    $isRoot = false;

    if ($node == null) {
        $node = Doctrine_Core::getTable('YOURNESTEDTABLENAME')->findOneById($id)->getNode();
        if ($node->isRoot()) {
            $isRoot = true;
        }
    }
    $record = $node->getRecord();

    if (!$isRoot) {
        echo "<li class='tree_item' id='list_". $record->getId() . "'>"; 
        echo "<div class='listitem' id='listitem_".$record->getId()."'>";
        echo $record->getName();
        echo "<div style='clear:both'></div>";
        echo "</div>";

        if ($node->hasChildren()) {
            echo "<ol>";
            foreach ($node->getChildren() as $child) {
                self::display_node($child->getId(), $child->getNode());
            }
            echo "</ol>";
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($node->hasChildren()) {
            echo "<ol class='sortable'>";
            echo "<li class='tree_item root_item' style='position: relative;' id='list_". $record->getId() . "'>";
            foreach ($node->getChildren() as $child) {
                self::display_node($child->getId(), $child->getNode());
            }
            echo "</ol>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

You can also easily modify the code to add URLs as you wish.
Hopefully this helps.  Let me know if you require clarification.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for this! It that makes sense to me. My root nodes are `0`. I'm trying to call this function from with a component, but I'm a little unsure how I should be using `$categoryid`.

Comment: @Jon at the moment I have: `$categoryid = '1';
        $this->header = TreeTable::display_node($categoryid);` this only seems to display a single child node and not any others be ir parent or child. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Category is the "entity" that I have setup using NestedSets.  In your case, it would be something like PageID.  You can query your NestedSet model the way you want, I simply used the ID as it is unique to each of my categories.

Comment: Ok, does this same code power the menu on: http://cart.samedraw.com/ this is what I'm really after. I have a nestedset admin module, just not a frontend navigation menu, like what you have.

Comment: I cleaned up the code a little for you, it might be a little clearer.  I removed the "fake root" node from the equation.  The code is not the same as the cart.samedraw.com site, but modified since a lot of the code is specific to my implementation.  You can see all of it here https://github.com/jongallant/sfCartPlugin ... Or specifically in this file https://github.com/jongallant/sfCartPlugin/blob/master/lib/cart.php

Comment: Sorry, misread your last comment.  The code for the frontend generation is in that cart.php file mentioned above.  The function is called display_sub_categories() -- This function is very rugged, and needs to be improved on.  It will only display 3 levels of nested sets at once, whereas the admin one will display them all at once.

Comment: Wow, that seems a lot of code for what I'm trying to do. I just thought I could get the root nodes and iterate through them to get the children for each one. And display in some kind of menu

Comment: Yeah, the code in my answer will do that.  It can be used in the frontend, you can simply modify it to your needs.  The reason there is so much code, is to get the <li> <ol> tags to render properly, in order to show indentation.

Comment: There is also another example [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/nl/hierarchical-data#nested-set:rendering-with-indention) which uses spaces instead of list tags.  I don't personally like this implementation, but it might do the trick for you.

Comment: Yeah this is a little better. I might be able to add in list tags in that implementation

Comment: I've found something similar to the code you posted above. Seems a little bit hacky, but is almost what I'm after. The problem is, it doesn't render the URLs how I'd like: http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/t/23623/ I'd liek to have `/parent1` for root node and child as `/parent1/child2`

Comment: You can hard code the URLs if the list is generating properly.  Just add your <a> tag in there, and it should work.  You can do $node->getLevel() to determine what level the child is at.  0 would indicate a root node.

Comment: After some further digging around into sfCartPlugin, I'm getting some annoying behaviour. Everytime I insert a root node, it seems to put this as `root_id of 2`, with `Categories` being the name of the root node. Using the code post by @Dziamid below, gives me URLs of `/pages/parent-1/child-1`, which breaks. I'd prefer to have `/parent-1/child-1` but sfCartPlugin uses a default `root_id` as  default and the other roots seem to use this. Any nodes I change in phpmyadmin then do not display on either frontend/aadmin. All root nodes have a `level` of 1, rather than 0. Im just a little confused

Comment: I'm also having trouble displaying the child page of a parent. `/parent` displays fine, but `/parent/child` gives me: `Action "parent/child" does not exist.`

Answer (score 1):

I hate to echo view element anywhere other than templates, so here's my version.

```
//actions:
    public function executeShow(sfWebRequest $request)
    {
      $this->tree = Doctrine::getTable('Model')->getMenuTree();
    }

//lib:
    class ModelTable extends Doctrine_Table
    {
      /**
       * Gets tree element in one query
       */
      public function getMenuTree()
      {

        $q = $this->createQuery('g')
          ->orderBy('g.root_id')
          ->addOrderBy('g.lft')
          ->where('g.root_id NOT NULL');

        return $q->execute(array(),  Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY_HIERARCHY);
      }
    }

//template:

<?php function echoNode($tree, $parent=null) { ?>
  <ul>
  <?php foreach ($tree as $node): ?>
    <li data-id='<?php echo $node['id'] ?>'>
      <?php echo $node['name'] ?>
      <?php if (count($node['__children']) > 0): ?>
        <?php echo echoNode($node['__children'], $node) ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>       
  </ul>
<?php } ?>

<?php echo echoNode($tree) ?>
```

Now, if you need a part of tree, you can either do in an action or better yet, write a separate model method for that.

Comment: Ok, the Doctrine query threw an error, to do with the `where` clause. Another problem, is to get the urls in the form of `parent-1` for a parent node and then `parent-1/child-1` for a child node. Is that possible?

Comment: Well, you can remove where clause if you are sure that all objects are part of some tree (have root_id other than NULL). This may be the case when you migrate your model to nested set.

Comment: Yeah I just put `IS NOT NULL` and seemed to work. Regarding the routes/URLs, is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Absolutely, that's my fault. Didn't quite get your question about url. I suggest you start a separate question and better explain what you need.

Comment: I have asked a new question, with a more detailed explanation of the urls/routes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994668/nestedset-parent-child-nodes