# nestedSet - parent/child nodes

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I am currently working on  outputting a heirarchy in terms of a navigation menu from a nestedSet in Doctrine.

I have a number of parents that then have several children.

At the moment in time, there are only 2 levels: Parent and Child (no grandchildren).

I have the following code:

```
//actions:
public function executeShow(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->tree = Doctrine::getTable('Model')->getMenuTree();
}

//lib:
class ModelTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
  /**
   * Gets tree element in one query
   */
  public function getMenuTree()
  {

    $q = $this->createQuery('g')
      ->orderBy('g.root_id')
      ->addOrderBy('g.lft')
      ->where('g.root_id NOT NULL');

    return $q->execute(array(),  Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY_HIERARCHY);
  }
}


//template:
<?php function echoNode($tree, $parent=null) { ?>
  <ul>
  <?php foreach ($tree as $node): ?>
    <li data-id='<?php echo $node['id'] ?>'>
      <?php echo $node['name'] ?>
      <?php if (count($node['__children']) > 0): ?>
        <?php echo echoNode($node['__children'], $node) ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>       
  </ul>
<?php } ?>
<?php echo echoNode($tree) ?>
```

This renders out:

```
Parent Node 1
   Child Node 1
   Child Node 2
Parent Node 2
   Child Node 3
```

Which is great.

The problem is, that I'd like my URLs to match the parent/child relationship.

Thus the URL for Child Node 2, would be `/parent-node-1/child-node-2` (these as `slug` fields).

So any child of a parent, needs to have the parent node's route slug as well.

I hope that make sense?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one way to hadle this is to use `Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_RECORD_HIERARCHY` hydration, which allows you to call methods on your nodes.

Now you can create a custom method for a node:

```
class Model extends BaseModel
{
  public function __toString()
  {
    return $this->getSlug();
  }
  public function getUrl()
  {
    //getPath uses __toString method to render a node
    $url = $this->getNode()->getPath('/', true);
    return $url;
  }
}
```

And call it in template like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $node->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $node['name'] ?></a>
```

Comment: That worked prefectly! Think I'm understanding nestSet behaviour now!

Comment: One thing needs to be noted here is performance. Each call to getPath() results in a separate query to db. Here's an alternative solution with one query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009163/breadcrumb-navigation-with-doctrine-nestedset/6010461#6010461 (see my answer)

Comment: Yeah the solution above seem to create a few queries. One would be much better! I'll have a look at your example

Comment: Awesome! That reduced my queries from 12 to 4, with only 1 being that to render the tree! Thanks alot!

Comment: Ok, so I'm having problems with displaying the actual child nodes. I can display `/parent` but `/parent/child` throws an error: `Action "parent/child" does not exist.`

Comment: It's not related to this question. You need to create a custom route. Again, I suggest you start a new question.. and I'd be happy look into it.

Comment: I have asked the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055603/custom-route-for-doctrine-nestedset thanks