# custom route for doctrine nestedSet

Tags: symfony1, routes, symfony-1.4

I have been able to to successfully display all the nodes in a nice tree on the frontend, but the problem comes with rendering of the actual pages.

So I have 2 parents, `Dog` and `Cat`, and withing them I have multiple child nodes.

I have created a frontend module named `animals` that has an empty `indexSuccess.php` file.

In my `actions.class.php` file i have:

```
$this->animal = AnimalTable::getAnimalBySlug($request->getParameter('slug'));
```

In my Animal model

```
    public static function getAnimalBySlug($slug)
    {
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
          ->from('Animal a')
          ->where("a.slug = ?", $slug);

       return $q->fetchOne();
    }
```

I have a very basic route:

```
animal:
  url:   /:slug
  param: { module: animals, action: index }
```

So you see this will work fine for `/dog` (parent node), but not for `/dog/sheep-dog`

I'm not sure If i need to update my `getAnimalBySlug` and the route to take a dynamic route ini terms of a nestedSet.

Thanks

Comment: Check the log or symfony debug toolbar and see what the query is when you try to access the /dog/sheep-dog page - You can then see if the problem is the route or the function

Comment: I do think it is the route as it as the log returns: `May 19 11:34:19 symfony [info] {sfPatternRouting} Match route "default" (/:module/:action/*) for /dog/sheep-dog with parameters array (  'module' => 'dog',  'action' => 'sheep-dog',)
May 19 11:34:19 symfony [info] {sfFrontWebController} Action "dog/sheepdog" does not exist
May 19 11:34:19 symfony [err] {sfError404Exception} Action "dog/sheep-dog" does not exist.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the route to be :

```
animal:
  url:   /:slug
  param: { module: animals, action: index }
  requirements: { slug: '.*?' }
```

Comment: Ok so that seemed to get rid of the routing error I posted above. But this has given another problem. Looking at `$request->getParameter('slug')` now returns `/dog/sheep-dog` and thus passing `$slug` to `getAnimalBySlug` also now breaks the page when trying to access the `sheep-dog` fields. `Call to a member function getName() on a non-object`. Thanks

Comment: how are you accessing the `sheep-dog fields` ? post the template for the action - cause in the action it seems your only setting the `Animal` variable

Comment: I don't think the `$cms_page` is set - use `isset($cms_page)` and echo the result on the template

Comment: That returns nothing. The problem is because of the slug. Using the route you provided gives me the full path to `/dog/sheep-dog` I only need either `dog` if I'm on `dog` OR `sheep-dog`  If I'm on `/page/sheep-dog`

Comment: You need to create a couple of routes then - 1 for the /dog and one for /dog/*

Comment: Ok, but what If I then have multiple parent nodes, like `bird`, `reptile`, `amphibian`, `snake`? And then `/bird/pigeon`, `/bird/eagle`, `amphibian/turtle` etc etc

Comment: Then why not user `/:animal/:slug` as the route - then if slug is empty you can use `animal` as the slug lookup in the table ?

Comment: But this is a nestedSet, so `/:animal/:slug` is in fact `/:slug/:slug` i.e `dog` is a node, has a `name` and `slug` field. `sheep-dog` is a child node of `dog` and also has a `name` and `slug` field

Comment: If the slug field was the complete path that would make things easier for you

Comment: I know, but I don't have that at the moment. Just the parent and child relationship and each has it's own slug based on it's name field. Is there no way to route it using my current method?

Comment: Why not have 2 routes ... 1 that matches /*/:slug and 1 that matches /:slug

Comment: @sipher_z ... Sorry it took us so long to get there ... :-)